# TypeScript- How to add a Key Value pair to each object in an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I have an array of dates and an array of objects. I'd like to add the dates to the array of objects as a key value pair `{"Date": "10-12-18"}`.

**`dates`**:

```
["10-12-18", "10-13-18", 10-14-18"]
```

**`data`**:

```
[
   {"name":"One", "age": "4"},
   {"name":"Two", "age": "5"},
   {"name":"Three", "age": "9"}
]
```

I want something like...

```
[
    {"name":"One", "age": "4", "Date": "10-12-18"},
    ....
```

How can I do this in TypeScript? I'm used to normal JavaSCript and can't get it right.

Something I have so far:

```
for (let idx of data){
   data[idx].date = dates[idx] 
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: do it like in JS, typescript should compile vanilla JS without problem

Comment: Can you post the code you were using? Doing this in Javascript should be no different from doing it in Typescript. So if it wasn't working in JS, you are probably doing something wrong and typescript won't fix that

Comment: *"I'm used to normal JavaSCript and can't get it right."* What have your non-right solutions looked like?

Comment: Edited with my attempt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with your code is that `idx` will be the object not the index as you are using `for...of`. Use a simple regular `for` like:

```
for(let idx = 0; idx < data.length; idx++) {
    data[idx].date = dates[idx];
}
```

Or use `forEach` to loop one of the arrays and use the index it provides to get the value from the other array:

```
data.forEach((obj, i) => obj.date = dates[i]);
```

Comment: Perfect and concise, thank you. I need to get the hang of transitioning into TypeSCript more. it's good to see the two things side by side!

Comment: @LaurenAH Actually this is still valid javascript as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
const result = data.map(({ name, age }, index) => ({ name, age, date: dates[index] }));
```

just map the array to the result.

Answer (score 2):

Something like that:

```
    let dates = ["10-12-18", "10-13-18", "10-14-18"];

    let objs = [{"name":"One",
     "age": "4"},

     {"name":"Two",
     "age": "5"},

    {"name":"Three",
     "age": "9"}
    ]

    const result = objs.map((item, index) => {
        item.Date = dates[index];
        return item;
    });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: BTW, using `map` is totally unecessary here as you are altering the original objects so a simple `forEach` will do. `console.log(objs);` to see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

According to [@Jonas Wilms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5260024/jonas-wilms) answer,I think that the [map operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is the best solution.

You can also use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) instead of destructuring the object, like this :

```
const data = [
   { 'name':'One', 'age': '4' },
   { 'name':'Two', 'age': '5' },
   { 'name':'Three', 'age': '9' }
];

const dates = ['10-12-18', '10-13-18', '10-14-18'];

const result = data.map((object, index) => ({ ...object, date: dates[index] }));
```

In case of long objects, it avoids you to rewrite every key of your object.

Answer (score 0):

In TS, you can do this like below..

```js
var data = [{
    "name": "One",
    "age": "4"
  },

  {
    "name": "Two",
    "age": "5"
  },

  {
    "name": "Three",
    "age": "9"
  }
];

var dates = ["10-12-18", "10-13-18", "10-14-18"];

console.log(data.map((ob, i) => ({ ...ob,
  "Date": dates[i]
})));
```